# Railgun magnetic force does no work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism

Railgun magnetic force does no work?

Q1) The Lorentz magnetic force on a moving electron is always perpendicular to its motion; so no work is done. Yet, why is work done in railgun operation.

Q2) For every action, there must always be a reaction. The recoil force of the railgun will be transmitted to the structure holding the rails. But what is the actual mechanism that transfers the force of reaction?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, in situations like this where it looks like the magnetic component of the Lorentz force might be doing work, what is usually happening is there is an electric field somewhere that is "mediating" the energy transfer. Here is how it works in this case. Suppose the projectile is in motion and being accelerated.

1. A current is being made to flow through the projectile. Positive charges have a velocity component in the same direction, as well as a velocity component in the direction of motion of the projectile.
2. Because of the motion of the projectile, there is a component of magnetic Lorentz force on positive charges in the direction that opposes current flow.
3. An electric field in the direction of the current is induced in the projectile, to counteract this force.
4. Since positive charges have a velocity component in the direction of current flow and the electric Lorentz force is also in that direction, it is this force that is responsible for energy transfer to charges.

Comment: I don't understand why there is current of +ve charges (lattice nucleus). The initial velocity of armature must be zero! So cannot assume any motion of +ve charges of the armature.

There is explanation of railguns using Ampere's force laws between current elements of rails and armature. The recoil is true Newtonian law three reaction on the rails, a compressive force.

Comment: The conduction doesn't have to be due to positive charges. It can just be slightly easier to think of it that way, because positive charges would move in the direction of current. What really matters in this scenario is the Lorentz force *per unit charge*, which depends on the current and but not the sign of charge. You can actually carry out the same reasoning in the answer for electrons (essentially flipping the velocity component due to current flow), and you will arrive at the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Q1)

"Lorentz force does not work" is true only for magnetic force acting on a single point charged particle.

Macroscopic magnetic force acting on current-carrying bodies like wires may do work. It is a different kind of force than the Lorentz force in the first statement is; it is a result of all forces, external and internal, acting on the projectile.

Q2) In EM theory Newton's 3rd law does not hold in general, only in special circumstances it does. In railgun there is a recoil, but there is no "mechanism" - it is due to ponderomotive EM forces (EM forces acting on matter) acting back on the parts of the gun.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic force cannot do work.

This is a fact.

However. What the magnetic force CAN do, is exert a force on particles. In any circumstances, where we solve that the magnetic force does "work", we are considering current distributions, that have some FIXED value.

Ie, the current must be in a LOOP, or the current must follow the wire.

For example, in a rail gun, the individual electrons want to spiral, but the   actual structure of the wire, stops the electrons from doing so, and forces them into a straight path.

In any realistic case where the magnetic force does work. In reality, it is the electric field, that does the work.

The electric field from the electrons, pushes against the structure of the wire, and then causes the macroscopic body to accelerate. No work is done on any individual electron via the magnetic force, but the magnetic forces ability to change the path of a electron, and able to change how its electric field interacts with the macroscopic structure, can.

*You Could just say that the "proof" for the fact that the magnetic field does no work, comes from the fact that, it is derived from the force on a single particle. And when finding the force on a current loop, it is of a different form that A single particle, and thus the fact that the magnetic field does no work wouldn't apply.*

But that seems disingenuous, because when we say "a current loop exists", we just assume that it just maintains its structure and that the particles themselfs don't just seperate. That is because when inputing that current distribution into maxwells equations, we aren't concerned as to HOW that current loop exists in the first place, we just say that it DOES exist.

Tdlr: the magnetic force does no work, the electric field does. Ignoring the fact that to maintain the structure we require other forces, we can just "say" that the magnetic force does work on macroscopic structures, when in reality, It doesn't, but that doesn't matter, since assuming the structure holds its shape, that structure, CAN accelerate due to the magnetic field.